# Corner radii won't show on buttons

Tags: android-layout

This is my first post here so please excuse if I do something wrong. I'm also new to Android Studio.

In one particular layout, rounded corners won't show up. If I paste the same code for a button which won't show with rounded corners into another layout, the rounded corners show perfectly.

I've removed background color, tint, everything. I've checked the code for both constraint layouts (one in which the bottons show with corners, and one in which they don't) and they're identical.

There's lots on here about adding a shape to the background of a button, but these are just default Android (Material view) buttons.

This is the code from the xml. I've included everything, but I doubt the Textviews or Sign in button are relevant.

The middle "button" is just constrained to the sides for testing purposes, and it still shows up without rounded corners.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/middleButtonCOPIED"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:cornerRadius="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginStatusTextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="40sp"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"
        android:autoSizePresetSizes="30sp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:background="@color/blue_light_background_VTG"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:foregroundGravity="clip_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Welcome! "
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline90percent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline10percent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></TextView>


    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/signInButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign In"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/signInTextview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline90percent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline65percent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/signInTextview">

    </com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signInTextview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Sign in with your Google Account."
        android:textColor="@color/flag_blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/userSettingsTextview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline50percent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline10percent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginStatusTextview" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userSettingsTextview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Personalize."
        android:textColor="@color/flag_blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/toFeedTextview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline50percent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline10percent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signInTextview" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toSettingsButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/flag_blue"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline90percent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline65percent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/userSettingsTextview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/userSettingsTextview" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toFeedTextview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Hungry?"
        android:textColor="@color/flag_blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signOutTextview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline50percent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline10percent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userSettingsTextview" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signInToFeed"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/flag_blue"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Feed"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:cornerRadius="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toFeedTextview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline90percent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline65percent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toFeedTextview" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signOutButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/flag_blue"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Sign Out"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:cornerRadius="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/signOutTextview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline90percent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline65percent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/signOutTextview" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signOutTextview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Sign out of your account. "
        android:textColor="@color/flag_blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline50percent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Vguideline10percent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toFeedTextview" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/Vguideline10percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/Vguideline90percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".9" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/Vguideline50percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.54" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/HGuideline20percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.10670315" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="left"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="signInTextview,userSettingsTextview,toFeedTextview,signOutTextview"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="41dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="right"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="signInTextview,userSettingsTextview,toFeedTextview,signOutTextview"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="41dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/Vguideline65percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="273dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".65" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who ever finds them in this situation, I solved it.

My Java activity loading it extended Activity, not AppCompatActivity. I guess it must have been to do with how I created that activity.